# IIS6 Web SIte Cannot be Accessed Remotely

Tags: iis-6, windows-2003-webserver

I have a Windows 2003 server, with IIS6 + .Net 4 installed.

I created a site running on port 8002. It could be accessed locally but not remotely. I have done following tests

- I used server's local broswer to access `http://192.168.1.107:8002/WebForm2.aspx` and I can get page successfully.
- I opened a broswer on remote machine to access `http://192.168.1.107:8002/WebForm2.aspx`, browser waited for long time and eventually displayed timeout, web page not available message.
- I tried `telnet 192.168.1.107 8002` from client machine, and the connection could be established. I believe I have Windows 2003 server firewall turned off, otherwise the port should be blocked.
- I ran `ping 192.168.1.107` from client machine and got response.
- While remote browser is waiting for response, I shut down the site (not IIS) and brwoser got not available right away. It looks like broswer connected to the site, but just something is hanging there.

What could cause such problem?

Answer (score 0):

what are your dns settings?  is the ip bound to this domain / host header?

recheck your settings in iis and check your firewall.

It sounds like you were able to reach the server, but I can only guess that based on what you're saying you tried already.

i would also make sure that nothing else is using that ip.

Answer (score 0):

OK, strange thing. I created the site in VS2012 and forgot to change target framework back to 4.0, so it was compiled as 4.5. But server has no 4.5 installed.

Once I changed the target framework everything works.

I just don't understand one thing, hwy it worked locally in 4.5.